# Convert SQL Server Query 2012 to 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

The Third Output is All I want
I query that using sql server 2012 using this query

```
Select LACCT,LREFNO,CONVERT(char(10), LDATE, 101) AS DATE,Description,Debit,Credit,Balance
From 
    (
        SELECT 
        LACCT, 
        LREFNO, 
        LDATE, 
        Description,
        Debit,
        Credit, 
        SUM(Debit - Credit) OVER (ORDER BY LDATE  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Balance
    FROM
        (
            Select  
                a.LACCT,
                a.LREFNO,
                a.LDATE,
                b.Description ,
                case when a.LDBCR = 'D' then cast(a.LAMOUNT AS decimal(20,2)) else '0.0' end Debit,
                case when a.LDBCR = 'C' then cast(a.LAMOUNT AS decimal(20,2)) else '0.0' end Credit

            FROM [dbo].[BCS02001] AS a
                 JOIN [dbo].[ref_LedgerParticulars] as b ON a.LCODE = b.Code  
                 where a.LACCT= @AcntNo 
          ) LedgerTable ) tblAll where year(LDATE) = @YEAR
```

But this Query is not Running on SQL SERVER 2008 r2

```
OVER (ORDER BY LDATE  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

How can I convert this to sql; server 2008 r2

thank you

Comment: There's no need to shout in your title (USING ALL CAPiTALS MAKES IT LOOK LIKE THAT'S WHAT YOUR DOING(!)). On topic, have you tried to resolve this already yourself? What did you try? Images of data aren't helpful, however, I'm afraid. The volunteers here can't interact with them. you'll be better off posting your sample data as `text`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this from the code:

```
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

It is something v2008 doesn't support. However, removing it will not change anything, as this line is the default window.